# dd($request->all()); gives back empty array

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to upload a photo from my Laravel 5 app to be stored in AWS. I am using the Postman REST client to test. When I upload a photo, the request returns an empty array. Does anyone know why this might be? Here's the code for my Avatar Controller:

```
class AvatarController extends Controller
{

  public function __construct(AWS $aws)
  {
      $this->aws = $aws;
  }

/**
 * Store a new avatar for a user.
 * POST northstar.com/users/{id}/avatar
 */
  public function store(User $user, Request $request)
  {
    dd($request->all());
    // dd($request->file('photo'));

    $file = $request->file('photo');
    // $file = Request::file('photo');
    // $file = Input::file('photo');

    $v = Validator::make(
      $request->all(),
      ['photo' => 'required|image|mimes:jpeg,jpg|max:8000']
    );

    if($v->fails())
      return Response::json(['error' => $v->errors()]);         

    $filename = $this->aws->storeImage('avatars', $file);

    // Save filename to User model
    $user->avatar = $filename;
    $user->save();

    // Respond to user with success
    return response()->json('Photo uploaded!', 200);
  }
}
```

Comment: Show your use statement please, code looks fine so maybe you imported the wrong request class?

Comment: here's my use statement:`use Northstar\Services\AWS;
use Northstar\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Validator;
use Input;
use Response;`

Comment: It's ok, and surely you are sending some kind of data throught postman?

Comment: yes! sending both a file (jpg image) and text data but nothing is showing up  in the array `dd($request->all());` sends. If I comment that out, this error is thrown, even though there is a photo in the photo field: {`"error":{"photo":["The photo field is required."]}}`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Found the answer - looks like there was an issue with my headers in Postman. I had both Accept application/json and Content-Type application/json. Once I removed Content-Type, all is fixed. Thanks!

Comment: could some one illustrate how to do this ?

Comment: @HosMercury if you open Postman and under the URL you should see four tabs - Authorization, Headers, Body, Pre-request script, and Tests. Click on the Headers tab and you should be able to type in the above! "Accept" goes in the left hand column and in the right column on the same row, you'd write "application/json" and same for "Content-Type" and again, "application/json" under on the next row. Hope this helps!

Comment: This did not work for me though it seems to be the method that works for almost everyone

Answer (score 8):

The same issue on postman, while using PUT/PATCH method directly.
One possible solution is to send your PUT/PATCH request **as a POST**, but include proper **_method** in the request body along with other parameters.

`_method: PUT`

Hope this helps

Answer (score 7):

Bit late to the party, but might be usefull for others:
My problem was that the `Content-Type` header value was `application/json` while the actual payload was form data. Changing the header to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` fixed the issue.

Answer (score 6):

Just want to add where i made a mistake.
When sending POST request with Postman, you also have to make sure the json is correct.

```
// invalid json (notice the ending comma)
{
    "akey":"aval",
    "nkey": "bval",
}

//valid json (no ending comma)
{
    "akey":"aval",
    "nkey": "bval"
}
```

Comment: This is an important point because Postman does not explicitly let you know that the JSON is malformed. Instead, it draws a curly underline under the malformed component which could be easily missed.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to test that the JSON is valid

```
$data = $request->all();
if(empty($data)) {
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent());
    $data = json_decode($data);

    if(is_null($data)) {
        return response()->json("Not valid json", 400);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try use this

```
dd($request->all());
```

Comment: Non-static method Illuminate\Http\Request::all() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Answer (score -1):

Try dd($request), dd($_REQUEST), dd($request->files).

Comment: Thanks all! Unfortunately, still an empty array/throwing an error. I'm thinking now that the request isn't coming through but since I am entering data in Postman and using Laravel's `Request`, shouldn't it be gathering the data?

Comment: Request {#41 ▼
  #json: null

Answer (score -1):

Although it wasn't the case in OP's question, this problem can also occur if you extend Laravel's Request class with your own.

```php
public function action(\App\Http\Request $request) {
    dd($request->input()); // This might be empty
}
```

In that case you can solve it by adding a line like this in your AppServiceProvider:

```php
$this->app->alias('request', \App\Http\Request::class);
```

Answer (score -2):

simply change in your Rout file

```
 Route::get('/users', 'AvatarController@store');
```

to

```
Route::POST('/users', 'AvatarController@store');
```

Answer (score -6):

Should be using:

`Request::all();`

As per documents: http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests

Comment: $request->all() is a perfectly fine way to reference the request's attributes.